# Can't access internet after installing NordVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, internet, macos-mojave

As soon as I install the NordVPN app from the app Store on MacOS Mojave, the internet connection dies. I can't use my browser, or any internet connected apps.

Deleting the app and then restarting the computer restores the internet.

With NordVPN installed, there are same symptoms even when I login to my user account in safe mode.

Pinging a website from terminal works fine.

What I have tried:

1. DNS flush
2. deleting my WiFi interface and adding it again
3. trying a different connection (using personal hotspot from my phone)
4. uninstalling NordVPN and deleting all the leftover files in cache
   etc. and then reinstalling the app again.
5. everything works well on a different admin account on the same Mac.
6. most of the advice I could find on the internet didn't help

I am suspecting that NordVPN is somehow turning on the kill switch as soon as it's installed. To that end, I tried turning the kill switch on and off on the app to rule that out and the internet still didn't work.

How do diagnose this? NordVPN customer service was of no use.

Comment: This question is very Mac specific. Might be more suited for "Ask Different", the Mac specific SE site.

Comment: It depends. It just happens to happen on mac. What the app is doing could be platform agnostic as in something to do with TCP handling etc.